# Lock Row for Particular Month

Tags: excel, vba

My data has cell A1 containing Month.

A2:Z999 : Employee details.
Column P: Date of joining.

I want to code such that, when P>A1, it should lock the row for that employee since it's old data. Only rows without date, or empty rows 999 onward, should be empty.

Please help! Right now my code below locks everything.

```
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long


Set DestSh = Sheets("Consultant & Teacher")

With DestSh
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lastrow = .Columns("A:z").Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Insufficient rows"

    End If

    If Range("A1").Value = "April" Then
    .Unprotect Password:="MyPassword"
    .Cells.Locked = False
    .Range("A2:Z" & lastrow).Locked = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what you were trying to accomplish with the existing code, but based purely on what you explained, I think this should do the trick :

```
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer

Set DestSh = Sheets("Consultant & Teacher")

With DestSh
    'finds the last row with data on A column
    lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    'parse all rows
    For i = 2 To lastrow
       'if your conditions are met
       If Month(.Cells(i, 16)) > Month(.Cells(1, 1)) Then
          .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Cells.Locked = True 'lock the row
       End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Doesn't work for me. I don't get any error but it doesn't lock the row.